# Escaping if/else in Jade template

Tags: pug

So I have a simply block of html in my jade template with a loop:

```
  each dude, i in dudes
    div(class='someClass')
      div.otherStuff
        span.someContent #{name}
```

I want to apply a data attribute to my top most div when a certain looping condition is met, in this case the first dude, I set it up like this

```
  each dude, i in dudes
     if i == 0
       div(class='someClass, data-someAttr='first dude')
     else
       div(class='someClass')
          div.otherstuff
            span.someContent
```

Setup like this it causes the `div.otherStuff div` and the `span.someContent` to only display on the else condition.  I've moved the tab spaces around on those items but I can't get it escape that else and give the `div.otherStuff` and `span.someContent` to both the first dude and the subsequent dudes after that.  I've also tried setting that data attr to a variable and trying to apply it that way but without any success.

What I end up doing to get around it is this:

```
  each dude, i in dudes
     if i == 0
       div(class='someClass, data-someAttr='first dude')
          div.otherstuff
          span.someContent
     else
       div(class='someClass')
          div.otherstuff
            span.someContent
```

How do I escape that `if/else` so I dont have to duplicate the `div.otherStuff` and `span.someContent`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the best way to do this would be using a regular mixin or a mixin attribute. You can read more about it [here](http://jade-lang.com/reference/mixins/)

An example of how to do this would be something like the following:

```
// Passing in index
mixin makeADude(index)
  if index == 0
     div(class="someClass", data-someAttr="FIRST")
  else
     div(class="someClass")

// Usage
   each dude, i in dudes
     +makeADude(i)
```

If you want to support nesting here then it would look like this:

```
// Passing in index
    mixin makeADude(index)
      if index == 0
         div(class="someClass", data-someAttr="FIRST")
           if block
             block
      else
         div(class="someClass")
           if block
             block

// Usage
   each dude, i in dudes
     +makeADude(i)
       h1 This is embedded inside the div.someClass
```

I think however for this question the best thing would be to use a `mixin attribute`

To do that it would be very similar

```
// Pass nothing
mixin makeAnotherDude()
  div(class="someClass")&attributes(attributes)
    if block
      block

// Usage
  +makeAnotherDude()(data-someAttr="FIRST")
    h1 This is embedded inside the div.someClass
```

So in your case using the mixin attributes syntax it might look something like this:

```
each dude, i in dudes
  if i == 0
   +makeAnotherDude()(data-someAttr="FIRST")
     h2 Other things here perhaps
  else
   +makeAnotherDude()()
     h2 Other things here perhaps
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to do :

```
each dude, i in dudes
   div(class='someClass', data-someAttr=(i==0) ? 'first dude' : '')
      div.otherstuff
        span.someContent
```

So if `i == 0`, Jade *will* render your `div` with `data-someAttr` set to `'first dude'`, and if `i != 0`, Express *should*  render your `div` with `data-someAttr` set to "", *but*, Jade being the clever guy here, the attribute won't be set at all if its value is an empty string, or `undefined` or `null`.

Hope that works for you.

Comment: This works as well, I just think the other answer is more what I was looking to do.  But this works as well for anyone else.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback. Interesting technique from Mike !